# CMake execute_process not generating output_file on windows

Tags: windows, cmake

I am writing a CMake script to generate some diff tests for me. The idea of the test is to generate two files and diff them, and the result is successful if they are identical.

Here is the relevant portion of my script:

```
# pretty_print built_in generation
message("")
message("Generating ${BUILT_IN_TMP_FILE}")
execute_process(
   COMMAND ${DEBUG_EXE} ${BUILT_IN_ARGS}
   RESULT_VARIABLE TEST_ERROR
   INPUT_FILE ${MCR_FILE}
   OUTPUT_FILE ${BUILT_IN_TMP_FILE})

# standalone first step - generate the unformatted debug file
message("Generating ${STANDALONE_TMP_FILE}_step1")
execute_process(
   COMMAND ${DEBUG_EXE}
   RESULT_VARIABLE TEST_ERROR
   INPUT_FILE ${MCR_FILE}
   OUTPUT_FILE ${STANDALONE_TMP_FILE}_step1)

message("Generating ${STANDALONE_TMP_FILE}")
execute_process(
   COMMAND ${MDF_PRETTY_EXE}
   RESULT_VARIABLE TEST_ERROR
   INPUT_FILE ${STANDALONE_TMP_FILE}_step1
   OUTPUT_FILE ${STANDALONE_TMP_FILE})

if ( TEST_ERROR )
   message( FATAL_ERROR "Test failed, returned ${TEST_ERROR}" )
else()
   message("Files generated sucessfully")
endif()
```

When I build my system on linux everything goes well and I end up with three files generated and this output:

```
47: DEBUG_EXE: /debug
47: MDF_PRETTY_EXE: /mdf_pretty

47: Generating /mdf_pretty_built_in.tmpoutput.txt
47: Generating /mdf_pretty_standalone.tmpoutput.txt_step1
47: Generating /mdf_pretty_standalone.tmpoutput.txt
47: Files generated sucessfully
1/1 Test #47: Osaka.Itch.v1_02:mdf_pretty_diff_test ...   Passed    0.05 sec
```

However when I turn to windows and run the same test I am getting this:

```
47: DEBUG_EXE: /debug.exe
47: MDF_PRETTY_EXE: /mdf_pretty.exe

47: Generating Z:/mdf_pretty_built_in.tmpoutput.txt
47: Generating Z:/mdf_pretty_standalone.tmpoutput.txt_step1
47: Generating Z:/mdf_pretty_standalone.tmpoutput.txt
47: CMake Error at Z:/mdf_pretty_diff_test.cmake:69 (message):
47:   Test failed, returned The system cannot find the file specified
47:
47:
1/1 Test #47: Osaka.Itch.v1_02:mdf_pretty_diff_test ...***Failed    0.29 sec
```

When I investigate my build directory I notice that on windows none of my files (what I specify in the `OUTPUT_FILE` argument) are present whereas on linux they are. The test is failing when it tries to use the `mdf_pretty_standalone.tmpoutput.txt_step1` as the `INPUT_FILE` for the third `execute_process`.

Any ideas? Is there something I am forgetting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for errors at all the stages, not just the final one.  The earlier generation steps are probably also failing (perhaps due to directory permissions?), but you are not looking at the error message.

Put your `TEST_ERROR` check and message after each of the `execute_process()` calls.

Comment: You are correct - it is now failing after the first one with `Test failed, returned Access is denied`

Comment: You should really be putting this output in a directory local to your build tree.  You probably want to use `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}` as a prefix for all of your temp files.

Comment: Also, the fact that this succeeds on Linux with binaries and output files in the root directory suggests that you're running your build as root, which is not a good idea.

Comment: I shortened the file/binary paths in the question for clarity and simplicity - I am not actually generating them at the linux root directory.